# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Wed Nov 06 2019 19:50:56 GMT+0500 (Uzbekistan Standard Time))

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Newbie in react, trying to play with it, but I got this problem.

I wrote some JavaScript, but I get the above stated error:

```
class Content extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.date = {new Date()};
  }
  state = {};

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="alert alert-success">{this.date}</div>  
  }
}
```

if i add something like `this.date = 'hello world'` and then return it, that works fine, but if I try to assign `new Date()` for `this.date` I get this error. 
How do I solve it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the date to string before displaying it, since `new Date()` returns an object:

```
class Content extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.date = new Date();
  }
  state = {};

  render() {
    return <div className="alert alert-success">{this.date.toString()}</div>;
  }
}
```